# WiX install based on Office Version

Tags: templates, wix, installation, ms-office, add-in

I have a c# custom install (has the 1 embedded resource to install) that adds a .DOTM file to the Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office*\STARTUP folder.  My company would like me to turn it into an MSI.  We have several versions of office (3 currently).  I do not want to create an install that just copies the same file to all possible versions of Office, but instead copies to the actual installed version.  I'm restricted from using Custom Actions unless already part of WiX.  Soon we will migrate to Windows 10 and Office 2016 and I would prefer to not have to create he MSI again, or when we add a new version of office if possible.

I know the version info can be found in the registry.  I'm hoping I can use conditional statements in WiX or some such, but I've never had to use conditional statements before in WiX either...  I've never done a complex install using WiX unless I used a custom action.

Can someone point me to a "How To" or give me an example?